# F# Invoke Function in Module

Tags: f#

I'm trying to write an installer for my application that runs (mostly) a bunch of database migrations.

I have a very simple start here, I'm just trying to figure out what `invokeMethod` should equal.

```
let RunMigration (fsModule: System.Type) =
    fsModule.GetProperties()
        |> Array.filter (fun property -> property.Name = "run")
        |> Array.map(fun property -> property |> invokeMethod ; "Ran successfully")
        |> String.concat "<br/>"

let RunAllMigrations =
    Assembly
        .GetExecutingAssembly()
        .GetTypes()
        |> Array.filter FSharpType.IsModule
        |> Array.filter (fun fsModule -> fsModule.Namespace = "DredgePos.Migrations")
        |> Array.map RunMigration
        |> String.concat "<br/><hr/>"
```

At the moment as you can see it is a fairly simple process of

1. Get all the types in the assembly
2. Getting all modules in the `Migrations` namespace.
3. Then if that module has a function named `run`, I want to invoke it.

How do I invoke it?

EDIT:

The `run` method will always be Unit -> Unit

```
let run () = ()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `RunMigration` method, you are getting a list of properties of the type - but a function declared as in your example should be compiled as a method. For example, if I have the following module in the current assembly:

```
module XX = 
  let run () = printfn "hello!"
```

It should be possible to invoke this if the `RunMigration` function first finds the `run` method and then calls the `Invoke` operation with no arguments (and `null` as the instance, since this is a static method):

```
let RunMigration (fsModule: System.Type) =
  let mi = fsModule.GetMethod("run")
  mi.Invoke(null,[||]) |> ignore
```

This returns `obj` value, which will be `null` (as the method returns `unit`) and so you can typically ignore the result.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. It's been a while since I've worked with nullables. Do I have to handle if GetMethod("run") returns null?

Comment: You will, if `GetMethod("run")` doesn't find a method it will return a `null` MethodInfo. You can pattern match on `null` to turn it into an option or do something else with it.